# How can I merge all PDF in one file with wickedpdf?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pdf, pdf-generation, wicked-pdf

The way I'm working right now is I'm generating multiple pdf files and sending them all one at a time for the user to download, but the problem is sometimes they end up with too many files.

How can I merge all pdfs in a single file before sending them to the user?

Answer (score 2):

I use [`combine_pdf gem`](https://github.com/boazsegev/combine_pdf).

> To combine PDF files:

```
pdf = CombinePDF.new
pdf << CombinePDF.load("file1.pdf") # one way to combine, very fast.
pdf << CombinePDF.load("file2.pdf")
pdf.save "combined.pdf"
```

> You can also parse PDF files from memory. Loading from the memory is
>   especially effective for importing PDF data recieved through the
>   internet or from a different authoring library such as Prawn:

```
pdf_data = prawn_pdf_document.render # Import PDF data from Prawn
pdf = CombinePDF.parse(pdf_data)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use some tool like `PDFTk` or `CombinePDF`, all you should need to do is prerender your individual PDFs by using something like:

```
pdf1 = render_to_string(pdf: 'pdf1', template: 'pdf1')
pdf2 = render_to_string(pdf: 'pdf2', template: 'pdf2')
```

or

```
pdf1 = WickedPdf.new.pdf_from_string(some_html_string)
pdf2 = WickedPdf.new.pdf_from_string(another_html_string)
```

If those tools won't take a PDF as a string, you may need to write them to tempfiles first.

If you don't want to introduce another dependency to merge things, `wkhtmltopdf` can take multiple pdf files (or urls), and render them all as one pdf with a command similar to this:

```
wkhtmltopdf tmp/tempfile1.html tmp/tempfile2.html tmp/output.pdf
```

Knowing this, you could prerender your templates, with layouts and everything, out to HTML strings, then pass them into wkhtmltopdf something like this:

```
# app/models/concerns/multipage_pdf_renderer.rb
require 'open3'
class MultipagePdfRenderer
  def self.combine(documents)
    outfile = WickedPdfTempfile.new('multipage_pdf_renderer.pdf')

    tempfiles = documents.each_with_index.map do |doc, index|
      file = WickedPdfTempfile.new("multipage_pdf_doc_#{index}.html")
      file.binmode
      file.write(doc)
      file.rewind
      file
    end

    filepaths = tempfiles.map{ |tf| tf.path.to_s }

    binary = WickedPdf.new.send(:find_wkhtmltopdf_binary_path)

    command = [binary, '-q']
    filepaths.each { |fp| command << fp }
    command << outfile.path.to_s
    err = Open3.popen3(*command) do |stdin, stdout, stderr|
      stderr.read
    end

    raise "Problem generating multipage pdf: #{err}" if err.present?
    return outfile.read
  ensure
    tempfiles.each(&:close!)
  end
end
```

And call in your controller something like this:

```
def fancy_report
  respond_to do |format|
    format.pdf do
      doc1 = render_to_string(template: 'pages/_page1')
      doc2 = render_to_string(template: 'pages/_page2')
      pdf_file = MultipagePdfRenderer.combine([doc1, doc2])
      send_data pdf_file, type: 'application/pdf', disposition: 'inline'
    end
  end
end
```

However, this only covers the simplest of cases, you'll have to do the work of rendering the headers and footers if you need them, parsing (or adding) any options you might need.

This solution originally came from https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf/issues/339 so it may be helpful to look there for more details on this strategy.

Comment: hi @Unixmonkey I have a service object rendering a PDF. It basically passes a `render_to_string` object back to where it is called. I have tried to implement your solution to composite PDFs. Had to replace `WickedPdfTempfile` by `WickedPdf::WickedPdfTempfile` for my service object to return something. But it is delivering code in another format. (I just see a massive string instead of the PDF data) Any idea what is wrong ?

Comment: (Also some PDF to be composited are actually images scanned into PDF format, maybe this is the problem)

Comment: @Maxence It sounds like the massive string is the PDF in String form (it starts with '%PDF' and ends with '%EOF'). To transform it to a real pdf, you need to either send it with a browser with the mime type of `application/pdf` (which `send_data` does above), or you need to write the file to disk (or temporary file, or IO string) in binary mode. To not derail this answer, please open a new question and tag me in a comment, or open an issue on the Wicked PDF GitHub page if you need more help.

Answer (score 1):

Try [PDFtk](https://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/). In my opinon, it is the best library for editing PDF files, and there are some gems that wraps it for access from Ruby.

Comment: My PDF's are generated dinamically, will that be a problem when using PDFtk? Since the contents in my PDF change from each user.

Comment: You can apply PDFtk each time.

Comment: Take a look at its syntax and see if you can handle that, it you are interested. It is capable of combining multiple files.